# Unable to install redux-devtools

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

I am using react 17.0 and while installing redux-devtools with the command npm install --save-dev redux-devtools the following error is thrown

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: login-form@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from redux-devtools@3.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/redux-devtools
npm ERR!   dev redux-devtools@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/sudheer.hr/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sudheer.hr/.npm/_logs/2022-01-28T08_50_19_096Z-debug-0.log
```

Any suggestions this regard will help

Comment: type this `npm install --save-dev redux-devtools --force`

Comment: if for typescript, you may need:   npm install --save-dev   @types/redux-devtools

Answer (score 1):

`redux-devtools-extension` does't work because it is deprecated.

You can try this :

```
npm i @redux-devtools/extension

import { composeWithDevTools } from "@redux-devtools/extension";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

Or you can force install by :

```
npm install redux-devtools-extension --force
```

or

```
npm install redux-devtools-extension --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: npm i is not deprecated; npm i and npm install are the same. The other two commands suggested by you are just another flag that helps bypass this npm error.

Comment: I am not saying npm i is deprecated, I'm saying redux-devtools-extension is deprecated. And workaround is npm i @redux-devtools/extension

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest Node v15 and npm v7 releases, npm install redux-form will fail.

I believe this is due to some changes in NPM.

Run this command instead:

```
npm install redux-form --legacy-peer-deps
```

Worked for me today!